# How to return two variables from a python function and access its values without calling it two times?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following function:

```
def f():
   return [1,2,3], [4,5,6]
```

I can call this function successfully like below:

```
a,b = f() 
print(a,b) #prints [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
```

But suppose that I want to have access only to the first item (1) of the first list and the first item (4) of the second list. To do that I call it like below successfully:

```
a,b = f()[0][0], f()[1][0]
print(a,b) #prints 1 4
```

I do not control function `f()` as it is written in a library.

Is it possible in Python to do the last operation, without calling the function two times and without using the returned a and b values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an [extended unpacking assignment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> def f():
...    return [1,2,3], [4,5,6]
... 
... 
>>> [a0, *rest], [b0, *rest] = f()
>>> a0, b0
(1, 4)
```

Using zip-splat trick:

```
>>> next(zip(*f()))
(1, 4)
```